# Python Pandas read excel time field, get inaccurate results

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Why I read a excel file (.xlsx) time field using `pandas` get inaccurate results ( millisecond )?

Excel content:

[image: Excel content]

Excel Field format: datetime

[image: Excel Field format]

Python Code:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import django

excel_file_name = 'All.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(excel_file_name, sheet_name=None)
df_athletes = data.get('Athletes')

# Print result
print(df_athletes['400M'])
```

And the result is :

```
0     00:01:07.560000
1     00:01:05.090000
2     00:01:14.990000
3     00:01:10.070000
4     00:01:09.840000
5     00:01:12.910000
6     00:01:16.620000
7     00:01:16.190000
8     00:01:12.390000
9     00:01:12.340000
10    00:01:15.290000
11    00:01:17.310000
12                NaN
13                NaN
14                NaN
15                NaN
16    00:01:22.120000
17    00:01:21.780000
...
...
```

The results seen not accurate at milliseconds.

How to get a accurate time from Excel using `pandas` ?

Comment: The results look _more_ accurate in pandas. Your spreadsheet seems to be displaying rounded to `.1 ms`. `01:07.6 ≈ 00:01:07.560000 `, `01:05.1 ≈ 00:01:05.090000` are you looking to round to match or alter the pandas display in some way?

Comment: Are you sure it's not how it's stored in the spreadsheet but the display was rounded?

Comment: @HenryEcker @mozay My fields in excel store in datetime format.  So, Do I need to change excel format or I can round the time from `pandas` ?

Comment: It depends what you want to do. You can change the _display_ (without altering the data in the DataFrame) or the _values_ in the DataFrame. You can also alter the spreadsheet which would also affect the DataFrame values read in.

Comment: @HenryEcker If I can't modify my file, How can I change my code to get the same values like excel display?

Comment: Excel does not store dates "in datetime format". It stores them as *floats* and only displays them as dates if you ask it to. To see what is really in the data, change the number display format to General.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I prefer to use code to round the values.
(Other way is modify the excel file)

And the code below can round the value to fit the excel value.

Code :

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

excel_file_name = 'MyFile.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(excel_file_name, sheet_name=None)
df_athletes = data.get('Athletes')

# Format time to datetime and round the milliseconds
df_athletes['400M'] = pd.to_datetime(df_athletes['400M'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f')
df_athletes['400M'] = df_athletes['400M'].dt.round('100L')
```

Result:

```
0     00:01:07.6
1     00:01:05.1
2     00:01:15.0
3     00:01:10.1
4     00:01:09.8
5     00:01:12.9
6     00:01:16.6
7     00:01:16.2
8     00:01:12.4
```